# Problem in Evolution @ Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, evolution

Recently I have installed 12.04 LTS from 10.04. After installing & Configuration of evolution, I am getting 2 Errors.

1. After sending mails to I am getting 
   Your message was sent, but an error occurred during post-processing. 
   The reported error was

> Failed to append to mbox:///home/bsm/.local/share/evolution/mail/local#Sent: Invalid folder URI 'mbox:///home/bsm/.local/share/evolution/mail/local#Sent'
>   Appending to local 'Sent' folder instead.

2. After installing ubuntu 12.04 LTS & Evolution, I am not seeing any .evolution folder in Home so that takeup the backup

Is there any advice to overcome these problems

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the following link to fix this.
https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/3.3/mail-error-failed-to-append-to-sent-folder.html.en

Also could you please specify which version of Evolution you are using?
Did you also tried configuring Thunderbird?